# Managing personal site on home computer

Tags: ssh, remote-management

I have a site on my personal computer (with OS Ubuntu 16.04), there is static IP so I can go to my site from anywhere. I am trying to find a way to manage and configure my site remotely.

My first approach was to establish connection through FTP protocol in order to manipulate with `/var/www` directory (for example change a few lines in index.php or like this).

But I rejected it because this connection is far from secure.

Then I picked up the idea of SSH connection and putty application for remote administration.

But as far as I know all users connected by SSH will be locked in `/home` directory and I will not be able of sharing /var/www and so goal will not be achieved.

Can you point me a solid way of managing site remotely in order to include a few more people to work on this and not to force them to send corrections and ask me to replace files manually in `/var/www`..

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT ONE**

Site is dynamical and includes frontend and backend parts. For example there are a few python scripts which interact with MySQL database

Comment: Too broad question. Is your website only a set of static files (perhaps HTML), or are you using something more involved? You could consider using a version control system (such as [git](http://git-scm.com/)....), at least if your website is just made of static resources

Comment: If the site is dynamic, are your contributors expected to understand the web software underneath (e.g. to code in PHP or JavaScript or whatever web technology you are using), or are they just using the web interface to add content.... It looks like you want some Wiki software.

Comment: Most of them understand pretty well what is going on, some like designers should just change some pictures and that is it

Comment: Then you consider your contributors as developers, and they should be able to use `git`

Comment: Thank you for reply ! But then, after pushing to git, edited script must be restarted. How to restart script on my home machine remotly?

Comment: That is a different question. And you need to provide much more practical details (what *exact* software and web server you are using, what are your scripts.....) to get any meaningful answer. You might even use `git` hooks.

Comment: Do I understand it correct: I do not need any kind of ssh or ftp or ... What I need is git?

Comment: You need to learn what `git` is (and `git` could internally use various network protocols, perhaps `ssh`). And you need to explain more in details your setup. BTW `ssh` could be setup with public and private keys (so no password entered at every use)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I will try to dissect git for my own purposes

Comment: Running a forced command via ssh at the server end is an option. It might be possible to combine this with a git push. Or Git itself should be able to run a post push script remotely - I suppose there are hooks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh is the most powerful and most popular remote tool. There are no limitations to /home or otherwise.

One common solution is to use git over ssh so dev's need only 'git push production' to make code live.